# How do I open a modal box, with contents from another page, where the URL changes upon clicking?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

How do I open a modal box, with contents from another page, where the URL
changes upon clicking (just like what Twitter.com does)?

Please see what Twitter.com does.

I have a simple example that works exactly as I want, except that the URL doesn't change when calling the Modal Box.

I have two files "Call.html" & "Test.html"

Here are the contents of the files:

Call.html

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a href="Test.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">Test</a>


<div id="Modal" class="modal fade text-center">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Test.html

```
Some Text ...
```

So let's say my website is called:  www.mysite.com

When I go to:

www.mysite.com/Call.html

and click on the hyperlink,

the modal box appears with the contents of Test.html

However, the URL stays the same (i.e. www.mysite.com/Call.html).

I would like the URL to change to:

www.mysite.com/Test.html

when clicking on the hyperlink (just like what Twitter.com does).

(Anyone know how to do that?)

Then, with the Modal Box open, when closing the Modal
box, I would like the URL to change back to 
www.mysite.com/Call.html   (Just like what Twitter.com does)

Anyone know how to do all of that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for this and even make it a bit more dynamic when selecting links to other pages:

```js
$(document).ready( function()
{
  //Add this on your call.html page
    $(".link").click(function()
    {
        //if you need the link to be dynamic you can use attributes on the element to set the url
        var hash = $(this).attr("data-url");
        console.log("page = " + hash);
        
        //set hash on url to whatever it is
        window.location.hash = hash;
                
        //Stop event bubbling up DOM
        event.preventDefault(); 
        
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log("page = " + page);
        
        //send a request to the server to retrieve your .html page
        $.ajax(
        {
          method: "GET",
          //this should be updated with location of file
          url: page, 
          //if server request to get page was successful
          success: function(result)
          {
            $(".modal-content").load(result)
          },
          //otherwise do this, note this example will fail as test.html doesnt exist in this location
          error: function(result)
          {
            $(".modal-content").html("<div class='error'><span><b> failed to get a response </b></span><p> try again later </p></div>");
          }
        });
    });
});

//revert url back to previous
function revertToOriginalURL() 
{
    var original = window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#'));
    history.replaceState({}, document.title, original);
}
    
//when modal is closed revert url back to previous state
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    revertToOriginalURL();
});
```

```css
.error
{
  border: 2px dotted red;
  margin: 5px;
}

a
{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a class="link" data-url="test.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal" href="test.html">Show Test.html</a>
<br />
<a class="link" data-url="test2.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal" href="test2.html">Show Test2.html</a>

<div id="Modal" class="modal fade text-center">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Be Aware that If no element is matched by the selector — in this case, if the
>   document does not contain an element with ".modal-content" — the Ajax request will not be sent.

---

### Update

From your comments it sounds like you are looking for: `window.location.hash`

I updated the example above for you to try on your own domain.

Comment: Hi Master Yoda, Thank you for your response.  I appreciate it.  I tried both versions you posted and the URL stays the same. I'm wondering if I explained my problem clearly.  When clicking on a link, then clicking in the browser's URL box, the location in the URL box stays the same.

But on Twitter.com, when clicking on a link, the location in my browser's URL box changes from "Twitter.com" to "twitter.com/User_ID/status/910982522".

And when closing the modal, the location in the URL box changes
from "twitter.com/User_ID/status/910982522", back to "Twitter.com".

Comment: Hey, which part of twitter do you mean? can you provide an example i can navigate to?

Comment: @Joe give my update a try. Not sure if it works on this domain but try on your own.

Comment: Hi Master Yoda - Thanks for responding! 
If you go to let's say LeBron James Twitter 
feed: twitter.com/KingJames 

His first post has a picture, ... click outside of the 
picture to read the post, and when you do, the location 
in the broswer's URL box changes from twitter.com/KingJames to 
https://twitter.com/KingJames/status/910931377213734912 

Then when closing the modal, the location in the browser's
URL box changes back to twitter.com/KingJames

Comment: Hi Master Yoda, what you did with the URL is pretty cool(!) 
but I'm getting your "failed to get a response try again
later" error message.  
The location in my browser's URL box is changing from 

www.mysite.com/Call.html

to

www.mysite.com/Call.html#test1.html

Comment: hmm ill have a look. Could be that your html pages are in a different directory to "~/test1.html" where do you store your .html files?

Comment: Hi Master Yoda - I have the three files in the same directory - the root directory.

Comment: @joe try that, just added an even better way of getting the root path and combined it with the page to get a full url

Comment: Hi Master Yoda, I'm still getting the same error after trying the new code.  

When clicking on the URL, www.mysite.com/Call.html
changes to 
www.mysite.com/Call.html#test.html

with the error message "failed to get a response try again later"

Comment: Okay, add this to your script and tell me what it says `console.log("full url = " + root + page);`

Comment: Also, try just passing the page through the url: `url:page,`

Comment: Hi Master Yoda, I don't know anything about consoles, but added the line to the top of the script "console.log("full url = " + root + page);"   Then I went to "Web Console" in Firefox and it said this: "ReferenceError: root is not defined"

Comment: Okay, use the updated code, i just removed the reference to root in the code

Comment: Hi Master Yoda, I get the same error, but this time without your error message "failed to get a response try again later"   

It still goes from 

www.mysite.com/call.html
to 
www.mysite.com/call.html#test.html


So then I added that console.log("full url = " + root + page); to the top of the script , and the Web Console shows:

page = test.html

Comment: If you arent seeing the "failed to get a response try again later" message that means the ajax request has been successful. You can test this by adding a log inside the success function. Dont go by the URL, go by the response object (result) in your success/error functions

Comment: Hi Master Yoda, I get the same error, without your error message,
but the screen goes dark when clicking on the link, without showing
the contents of test.html.  So when clicking on the link, it goes 
from www.mysite.com/call.html to www.mysite.com/call.html#test.html
I'm going to try adding a log inside the success function now like you said.

Comment: Hi Master Yoda, yeah, adding a log inside the success function, shows the result in the web console just fine.  But then the web page still has the empty modal box dark screen thing when clicking on the link.

Comment: You should update your question with the html for test.html. maybe there is something in there that's causing an issue.

Comment: Hi Master Yoda, I will be looking everything over this weekend.  Thanks for all of your help.  I appreciate it!

Comment: Hi Master Yoda, I was messing around with the code over the weekend,
trying to understand it (since I'm totally lost), in hopes that I can communicate better.  When I add href="Test.html" to the hyperlink, for example: 
<a class="link" data-url="Test.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal" href="Test.html">Show Test.html</a>
the Modal box works just fine i.e. Test.html displays just fine.  It doesn't seem that Test.html is an issue as  
the only thing Test.html contains is the following text:  "Some Text ..."

Comment: Also, is there a way to make it so that the link goes from:
www.mysite.com/Call.html to www.mysite.com/Test.html when opening the modal, then back to www.mysite.com/Call.html when closing the modal?  Right now it goes from www.mysite.com/Call.html to www.mysite.com/Call.html#Test.html
then back to www.mysite.com/Call.html

Comment: @joe, Point 1 - in that case check my latest update. It should now work as expected. Point 2 - I dont believe you can. You arent able to modify the full URL without redirecting, just the hash.

Comment: Thanks for your help Master Yoda - I appreciate it!